# Exception when trying to open an OracleConnectionObject

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to open a connection to my university's database that runs on Oracle 11g 11.2.0.1.0 (Oracle.ManagedDaraAccess v18.3.0 is installed on visual studio) with c#.

When I attempt to connect, it throws:

> Exception thrown: 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"

during the `con.open()` function at me with no further explanation.

Is there any way to see where the error occurs?

```
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        OracleConnectionStringBuilder ocsb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
        ocsb.Password = pass;
        ocsb.UserID = user;
        ocsb.DataSource = "<address>:<port>/orcl";
        con.ConnectionString = ocsb.ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
```

Comment: Add a try catch block around the open() call and resolve the ORA error that shows up in the OracleException.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my question, now I have to figure out how to fix ORA-12514

Comment: glad i could help

Comment: this might help: http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12514_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_service_requested.htm

Comment: @JohnB, you should add your comment as an answer so it can get accepted and shown for future visitors.

Comment: @Evan - posted as Answer if you wish to tick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a try catch block around the open() call and resolve the ORA error that shows up in the OracleException